# Post request using Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new in Express js and JS in general and after reading some documentation, I haven't been able to figure out how to do a Post request using Express JS.

Let's say I have the following third party API Service.

> http://thisUrl.net/apiservices/abc/v1.0

How could I do a Post request to it?
Also, how do I tweak the header to accept `application/json`?

I would appreciate a sample code..

Answer (score 1):

Using [`request`](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback):

```
request.post('http://example.com/endpoint', {json:dataObject}, handleResponse);
```

Note that I'm not setting the accept headers; that's something the server does.  using the json option in the second param will set the content-type, though, which is what you want when you're posting to something.

Comment: This makes sense to me but I am a bit lost with the using statement you called out here though.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

```
var router = express.Router();

router.post(URL, function() {
   //Do stuff here
});
```

Use `Express.Router()` and do have it `post` like the sample.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what version of your express, if it's `4.0`. you can use it such way:

```
app.post('/you path here', (req, res, next) => {

});
```

and remember that if you want to get the `form body` you post, you need to use such middleware: `body-parser method-override and body-parser`,

so you code should look like this:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';


app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }));

app.post('/you path here', (req, res, next) => {

});
```

Comment: I read it as he is trying to send a POST, to a third party API, not receive one.